# Can not able to echo Hindi Character in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to echo sql table in json format, the sql data is in Hindi and English language. I checked some answer it said use charset i tries that still now printing.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');

require "conn.php";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, 
$db_name);
if($conn === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM hindi_question ";




 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . 
 mysqli_error($conn));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
// echo json_encode($emparray);


echo json_encode(array("result"=>$emparray) , 
JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
//close the db connection
mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

The output is this

```
{"result":[{"sno":"1","question":"?????? ?? ???? ???\r\n?????? ????? ???????","o1":"?????? ?? ???? ???\r\n?????? ????? ???????","o2":"?????? ?? ???? ???\r\n?????? ????? ???????","o3":"?????? ?? ???? ???\r\n?????? ????? ???????","o4":"?????? ?? ???? ???\r\n?????? ????? ???????","r_o":"?????? ?? ???? ???\r\n?????? ????? ???????","tag":"?????? ?? ???? ???\r\n?????? ????? ???????","month":"?????? ?? ???? ???\r\n?????? ????? ???????","day":"11","lang":"Hindi"}]}
```

Any help or link to solve this will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In the database itself, do you see question marks as well or Hindi?

Comment: No in database there are text in Hindi language only

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
      mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
instead of 
      mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");